# How do I use MSHTML in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, mshtml

In the answer to question #[56107](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c), Erlend provided this sample c# code:

```
using mshtml;
...
object[] oPageText = { html };
HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocumentClass();
IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = (IHTMLDocument2)doc;
doc2.write(oPageText);
```

I'd like to use mshtml in VB.NET, but the IDE doesn't recognize this:

```
Imports mshtml
```

What additional steps do I need to take to use MSHTML in VB.NET?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found an answer to my own question:

[MSHTML in ASP.NET](http://web.archive.org/web/20081006160223/http://radio.javaranch.com/balajidl/2006/01/18/1137606354980.html)

> If you are interested, here is the solution based on VB.NET which you can use with 
>   ASP.NET(.aspx.vb). Make sure you add reference to Microsoft.mshtml from the .NET 
>   objects collection and "Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices"

With this clue, I found this by opening the "Add Reference" dialog, and looking under the COM tab, not the .NET tab.  It's Component Name was Microsoft HTML Object Library.

Answer (score 0):

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
and

"With this clue, I found this by opening the "Add Reference" dialog(project==>Add Reference), and looking under the COM tab, not the .NET tab. It's Component Name was Microsoft HTML Object Library."

it work 100%